# SQL get n results from each set with defined deviation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Using Oracle 11g and having a table like:

```
USER  | TIME
----- | --------
User1 | 08:15:50
User1 | 10:42:22
User1 | 10:42:24
User1 | 10:42:35
User1 | 10:50:01
User2 | 13:23:05
User2 | 13:23:34
User2 | 13:24:01
User2 | 13:24:02
```

For each user I need to get (if available) exactly 3 records with deviation between first and last less than a minute. If rows are more than 3 they won't match the criteria. Could you give me some clue?

The result should look like:

```
User1 | 10:42:22
User1 | 10:42:24
User1 | 10:42:35
```

Comment: Sorry, kinda new here. I'm using oracle 11g (added to the description.)

Comment: What happens if a given user has more than one group of 3 records all within a minute of each other?  What happens in this case?

Comment: What happens when there are 4 records within a minute? do you want a,b,c or b,c,d or both?

Comment: All groups have to be listed (even if it more than one).

Comment: What happens if we have `10:42:30` and `10:43:25` and `10:44:20`? It is more than 1 minute but the gaps in between are less than a minute.

Comment: 4 or more results have to be excluded.

Comment: @Salman I'd say that's a no - seems to be looking specifically for a cluster of 3 rows where the earliest date is less than a minute diff from the latest date

Comment: Deviation between first and last result should be less than a minute.

Comment: @Caius Jard - Yup, thats the case.

Comment: So when there are 4 records within minute, no records are to appear?

Comment: e.g. if User1 had `10:42:22 10:42:24 10:42:35 10:42:37` you don't want to see any of these times?

Comment: Is your time column actually a datetime, so that records that bridge midnight can be accurately assessed for being "within a minute"?

Comment: The data actually represents messages sent to users. We have to extract the data from a certain campagin. Unfortunately we dont have an unique tag to represent that the messages belong to this campaign. All we know is each user have 3 messages (if they are more or less that means thats something else).

Comment: Oh, so a list of users would be acceptable? You don't necessarily need the times, just the user..

Comment: List of users will aslo do the trick but times are kinda important to keep track when certain "events" happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use analytical `count()` with `range` clause:

**<sup>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0e2d3/1)</sup>**

```
select user_, to_char(time_, 'hh24:mi:ss') time_
  from (
    select user_, time_, 
           count(1) over (partition by user_ order by time_ 
                          range between interval '1' minute preceding 
                                    and interval '1' minute following) cnt 
      from (select user_, to_date(time_, 'hh24:mi:ss') time_ from tbl))
  where cnt = 3
```

Result:

```
USER_ TIME_
----- --------
User1 10:42:22
User1 10:42:24
User1 10:42:35
```

**Edit:**
As @CaiusJard noticed first answer may show incorrect values when there are intervals like `10:52:01, 10:53:00, 10:53:59`. There are some ways to correct this. First is to find min and max time in group and check condition `numtodsinterval( max - min, 'day') <= interval '1' minute`. Second is to number all rows, then assign flag to these row where prior, current and leading `count = 3`. 
Finally show flagged rows joined with original table:

```
with t as (
  select row_number() over (order by user_, time_) rn, tbl.*,
         count(1) over (partition by user_ order by time_ 
                        range between interval '1' minute preceding 
                                  and interval '1' minute following) cnt
    from (select user_, to_date(time_, 'hh24:mi:ss') time_ from tbl) tbl),
r as (select rn, 
             case when 3 = lag(cnt) over (partition by user_ order by time_) 
                   and 3 = cnt 
                   and 3 = lead(cnt) over (partition by user_ order by time_) 
                  then 1 
             end flag
        from t )
select * from t 
  join (select rn-1 r1, rn r2, rn+1 r3 from r where flag = 1) r
    on rn in (r1, r2, r3)
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm.

Comment: Neat trick, didn't know that Oracle could range things relative to the current row value.  I think this will have a couple of bugs.. see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9d2ae/1 - shouldn't be any rows out of this result set, according to Angel's rules. Consider wrapping the whole thing in a group by having count = 3?

Comment: Thanks @Caius. You are right. I modified answer and tested on two sample data sets, yours (no data returned, as expected) and one somewhat larger. [rextester test](https://rextester.com/CTK61332).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my stab at this. I don't have a live Oracle and SQLFiddle isn't working, so please advise how it turns out:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  u VARCHAR(5),
  t DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO t
  (u, t)
VALUES
  ('User1', '2001-01-01 08:15:50'),
  ('User1', '2001-01-01 10:42:22'),
  ('User1', '2001-01-01 10:42:24'),
  ('User1', '2001-01-01 10:42:35'),
  ('User1', '2001-01-01 10:50:01'),
  ('User2', '2001-01-01 13:23:05'),
  ('User2', '2001-01-01 13:23:34'),
  ('User2', '2001-01-01 13:24:01'),
  ('User2', '2001-01-01 13:24:02');

SELECT
    z.u,
    min(z.t) evt_start,
    max(z.t) evt_end
FROM
(
    SELECT y.*, SUM(prev_or_2prev_not_within) OVER(PARTITION BY u ORDER BY t ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as ctr
    FROM
    (
       SELECT 
           t.*, 
           CASE WHEN 
               t - LAG(t) OVER(PARTITION BY u ORDER BY t) < 1.0/1440.0 OR
               t - LAG(t, 2) OVER(PARTITION BY u ORDER BY t) < 1.0/1440.0
               THEN 0 ELSE 1
           END as prev_or_2prev_not_within
        FROM
           t
    ) y
 ) z
GROUP BY
    z.u,
    z.ctr
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

I believe it will establish an incrementing counter that doesn't increment when the previous or previousprevious row is within a minute of the current row. It does this by classing rows as 0 or 1, and when 0 occurs the sum-all-preceding-rows operation generates a counter that doesn't change. It then groups on this counter having exactly 3 occurrences. The partition makes the counter work per user

[image]

You can see it in action here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=018125210ecd071f3d11e3d4b3d3e670

It's SQL Server (as noted, I don't have an oracle) but the terms used for sqlserver and the logic should be broadly similar for oracle - oracle supports lag, unbounded sums, having etc, and it does date math in terms of dateA - dateB -> a floating point number representative of whole or parts of a day  (and 1440 minutes per day, 1/1440 should represent a float of one minute). The data types sqlserver uses might differ slightly to oracle, and this query does depend on TIME (I called it `t` - dislike column names that are reserved words/keywords) column being a datetime, not a string that looks like a time. If your data is a string, sort it out so it isn't (use an inner subquery to generate a datetime, or change your data storage so it's stored as a datetime type)

You said you wanted a result that tells the user and the event time - the simplest way to do that was to use min and max to give you the date range. If you're desperate to have all 3 rows on show, you can join the output of this query back to the table with date between evt_start and evt_end, or you can use some sort of string_aggregate type function to give you a list of times straight out of the outermost group operation

Comment: Thanks. I needed some time to run it since data type differences between oracle and mssql (as you mentioned above) and actually needed some time to get the whole idea behind :) but it's quite interesting and swift decision.

Comment: If the answer is useful, use the ^ arrow to give it an upvote. You can do this on any number of answers, but the green tick can only be given to one answer